# How to create a node with drupal restful web services that has a node reference field?

Tags: rest, drupal, backbone.js

I am using the Drupal Backbone module by ethanw with the Restful Web Services module providing the API. I can get nodes out of my Drupal database, and create a node, but am not able to set the node reference field.

Does anyone know the JSON syntax/structure for this? I've tried a ton of configurations, with my heart set on:

"field_tutorials_reference_q": {
   "nid": "191"
}

But that, and all the others I've tried, don't work. Also, to complicate matters, I'm using corresponding node references, but that's just a bonus, I can work around if only I could set a node ref field on one particular node type!

Do I need to set my own custom toJSON processor or something? Really frustrated, have been working at this forever, and now that it finally works, this last hurdle might make me reverse tack and go for a parallel Node.js + Express + Mongo configuration for the Backbone.js enabled parts of my site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this one:
    "field_tutorials_reference_q":{"target_id": "191","entity_type":"node"}